# Sorting a cell array with multiple datatypes in uitable using push button

Tags: sorting, matlab-guide, cell-array, matlab-uitable

I have a table of data in an uitable inputted by the user. There're 3 columns: Isotope, A and T_1/2. the Isotope column receive isotope names as strings while A and T_1/2 only receive numbers. An example of the table is like this (these are inputted by user also using a push button):

'C' '14' '2100000'

'Ra' '225' '14.9'

'U' '239' '0.0163'

Now i have to create a push button to sort the data by the criteria selected in pop-up menu (they're also isotope names, A (mass number) and T_1/2 (half-life)). I have no problem sorting the data by isotope name, but when i select A or T_1/2 in the pop-up menu i can't sort them. The command window doesn't even show any error of the code i wrote. Here's the code:

```
    data=get(handles.table,'data');
    switch get(handles.menu,'value')
case 1
    [data2 I] = sort(data(:,1));
    data=data(I,:);
case 2
    [data2 I] = sort(str2double(data(:,2)));
    data=data(I,:);
case 3
    [data2 I] = sort(str2double(data(:,3)));
    data=data(I,:);
otherwise
    end
    set(handles.table,'data',data);
```

I've been googling a few days but all those topics doesn't seem to solve my problem. Also i'm restricted to use the SORT function to solve this so im really stuck right now. Any help is appreciated!
[This is the GUI i created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP5il.png)

Comment: Can you give a sample `data` table so that your code snippet runs?

Comment: do you mean an example of what will happen to the data if i run that code? sorry, english is not my native language.

Comment: An example of what `data` is so I can run your code. Your English is fine!

Comment: oops :D ok, i think i mentioned an example of the data in my question above 'C' '14' '2100000';

'Ra' '225' '14.9';

'U' '239' '0.0163'

Comment: Is it an array of strings? A cell array? A table?

Comment: A cell array which contains 2 datatypes: 1 column is combination of text and numbers, 2 other columns contains numbers only